# What is the origin of the knock-knock joke?

Tags: etymology, jokes

Almost everyone knows about knock-knock jokes.  Who made them up, and why did they catch on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some claim they originated in the Middle Ages as a call-and-answer password format. Others, as @Callithumpian notes, cite passages in Shakespeare.

Here is a [legitimate reference](http://news.google.com/newspapers?id=v8oaAAAAIBAJ&sjid=IkwEAAAAIBAJ&pg=1725,682989&dq=knock-knock&hl=en) to their existence in America in 1936:

[image]

This is the first legitimate printed reference I can find.

Comment: Could you explain the Roosevelt one?

Comment: @Tim: "When I woke up and rose I felt awful."

Answer (score 5):

I found [this](http://books.google.com/books?ei=sNIFToedJs-10AGVktz_Cg&ct=result&id=DGwPAQAAIAAJ&dq=proceedings%20american%20pomological%20society%201933&q=knock%20knock#search_anchor) use of the joke in the printed "Proceedings" of the American Pomological Society. This publication seems to cover meetings from 1933 to 1937, but this occurrence is early enough (p. 75) that I think it can be dated to [1933](http://books.google.com/books?ei=sNIFToedJs-10AGVktz_Cg&ct=result&id=DGwPAQAAIAAJ&dq=proceedings%20american%20pomological%20society%201933&q=december%201933#search_anchor). I wondered if this was perhaps used as a jingle by an apple company, but I couldn't find evidence of this.

[image: http://books.google.com/books?ei=sNIFToedJs-10AGVktz_Cg&ct=result&id=DGwPAQAAIAAJ&dq=proceedings+american+pomological+society+1933&q=knock+knock#search_anchor]

Whatever the origin of the first joke, its form certainly came from *[Macbeth](http://books.google.com/books?id=rIE7AAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=macbeth%20shakespeare&hl=en&ei=Y8oFTqLxOYfHgAe8-fHLDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=knock%20knock&f=false)*:

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=rIE7AAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=macbeth+shakespeare&hl=en&ei=Y8oFTqLxOYfHgAe8-fHLDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=knock%20knock&f=false]

Comment: How certain can one be that the Shakespeare example isn't based on the fact that "knock knock" jokes were already common rather than being the spark for them?

Comment: If people understood and laughed at these jokes, I reckon it was because they were already in common usage round about then...

Comment: @Neil, et al.: I'm simply saying the _form_, or the phrase "knock, knock" followed by "who's there?" would have been familiar to people due to its use here in _Macbeth_. As to knock knock jokes being around in Shakespeare's time, I don't think you'll find any evidence of that outside of bogus _[Uncyclopedia](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Knock_knock_joke)_ entries.

Comment: Of course there's also the possibility of the "Knock knock / Who's there" answer/response arising independently at different times - after all, "Who's there?" is perhaps one of the most natural responses to someone knocking!

Comment: I can appreciate there's no evidence of knock-knock jokes around Shakespeare's time. So a related question: would we *expect* there to be? Is it the kind of thing that people habitually wrote down then? (Are there any extant "joke books" from around then?)

Comment: @Neil: Perhaps not, but if they are older than the 1930s, it's very likely someone would have turned one up in print—especially with tools like Google Books.

Comment: Well, it's interesting that in 1936 what is ostensibly a "knock knock" joke is being described as a "new" game, and the 'apple' reference above from the 1930s, plus e.g. this also from 1936 http://bit.ly/kWJqSB says: "but to open the ball this month with the novelty fox-trot Knock, Knock, Who's There ? Of course you have heard about this new musical game of the Schoolboy Howler type". So it is looking like around the 1930s was when they first sprang up, and possibly the Shakespeare example is just a red herring.

Comment: @Neil: I'd still argue the _Macbeth_ quote is part of the story in the same way that phrases such as _[sea change](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/312800.html)_, _[come what may](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/come%20what%20may.html)_, and _[foregone conclusion](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/141000.html)_ became common vernacular without conscious efforts to quote Shakespeare. The use in Macbeth helped make the structure of the later knock knock jokes sound familiar.

Comment: Well, today, I doubt most people have ever read or seen Macbeth, and even if they had, would they remember that particular scene, I wonder. And had they in the 1930s...? maybe more than nowadays, but still not sure. And why do the jokes apparently never or rarely have "Knock knock knock" three times? From what's been turned up so far, I'm inclined to regard the Macbeth scene as an interesting coincidence, but simply as that.